# 404 on handsontable after moving it to resource folder

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, handsontable

I am trying to install in spring boot application handsontable locally. After downloading, I moved the handsontable to the resource folder and registered the paths to the css and js files, but the browser keeps returning an error that the file was not found.

> handsontable:7 GET http://localhost/src/main/resources/static/handsontableV/dist/handsontable.full.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

My project structure:

[image]

My html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
    <title>Spring Security Example </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/main/resources/static/handsontableV/dist/handsontable.full.min.js" media="screen">
    <script src="src/main/resources/static/handsontableV/dist/handsontable.full.min.js"></script>
<!--    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handsontable@8.2.0/dist/handsontable.full.min.js"></script>-->
<!--    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handsontable@8.2.0/dist/handsontable.full.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/webjars/bootstrap/4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="/webjars/bootstrap/4.5.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/webjars/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

WebConfig :

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("src/main/resources/static/handsontableV/dist/handsontable.full.min.js")
                .addResourceLocations("src/main/resources/static/handsontableV/dist/handsontable.full.min.js");

        registry
                .addResourceHandler("src/main/resources/static/handsontableV/dist/handsontable.full.min.css")
                .addResourceLocations("src/main/resources/static/handsontableV/dist/handsontable.full.min.css");

        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/webjars/");

    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfig :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(8);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login", "/registration","/webjars/**", "/static/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }
```

Response from Google Chrome :

[image]

I do not understand. I tried changing the path to static / handsontableV / dist / handsontable.full.min.js

but it doesn't work. For what reason may spring not see the file?

Comment: You have `static.handsontable` and not `static/handsontable` in your folder structure

Comment: Yes, this is how idea writes, in finder static / handsontable

Comment: Sounds suspiciously weird to me

Comment: Why you add src/main/resources/static to script url if spring boot already use resource/static folder by default as a static folder, i think you should use this /handsontableV/dist/handsontable.full.min.js url for script

Comment: I also tried it, he still writes that he does not see the file

Comment: try to move jquery and bootstrap scripts before(upper) your handsontable scripts in order jquery,bootstrap,handsontable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to create a webapp folder

[image]